# In-App Purchase : Remove Ad Banners & Interstitial Ads - Code Assistance

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, iad, interstitial

I have a simple single view application project - a one (1) page app that displays some random text to the user.

I have successfully incorporated Ad Banners and Interstitial Ads.

I have set up another view controller (`InAppViewController.swift`) to handle a pop-up page that allows the user to make an in-app purchase to remove all ads (AdBanners & InterstitialAds).

In my second view controller (`InAppViewController.swift`), I have the following code:

**AMENDED CODE:**

```
//  InAppPViewController.swift

import UIKit
import StoreKit
import iAd

class InAppPViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var product_id: NSString?;


@IBOutlet weak var unlockAction: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var adBannerView: ADBannerView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    product_id = "holymoly.iap.removeads";
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    
    //Check if product is purchased

    if (defaults.boolForKey("purchased")){
        self.adBannerView?.hidden = true  
    }

    else if (!defaults.boolForKey("stonerPurchased")){
        print("false")
        self.adBannerView?.hidden = false    
    } 
}
   

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func unlockAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    
    print("About to fetch the products");
    // We check that we are allow to make the purchase.
    
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
    {
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
        let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        productsRequest.start();
        print("Fething Products");
    }else{
        print("can't make purchases");
    }  
}

func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);
}

//Delegate Methods for IAP

func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    
    let count : Int = response.products.count
    if (count>0) {

        let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            print(validProduct.localizedTitle)
            print(validProduct.localizedDescription)
            print(validProduct.price)
            buyProduct(validProduct);
        } else {
            print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
        }
    } else {
        print("nothing")
    }
}


func request(request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error Fetching product information");
}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])   {
    print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");
    
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
                
            case .Purchased:
                print("Product Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                defaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased")
                self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
                break;
                
            case .Failed:
                print("Purchased Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                self.adBannerView?.hidden = false
                break;
                
            case .Restored:
                print("Already Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions() 
                
                
            default:
                self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

And in my 'original' view controller (`ViewController.swift`) I have added this code:

```
//  ViewController.swift
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import Social
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,     MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate,  ADInterstitialAdDelegate
{ 

var interstitialAd:ADInterstitialAd!
var interstitialAdView: UIView = UIView()

@IBOutlet var adBannerView: ADBannerView?

@IBAction func someFunkyButton(sender: AnyObject) {
  
    //Interstitial Ad:
    
    let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))
    print(rand)
    let adNo = 2
    
    if(adNo == rand)
    {
        loadInterstitialAd()
        
    }
}

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //Check if product is purchased
   
if (defaults.boolForKey("purchased")){

        // Advertising Banner:
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        self.adBannerView?.delegate = self
        self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
        
    }
    else if (!defaults.boolForKey("stonerPurchased")){
        print("false")
        
        // Advertising Banner:
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        self.adBannerView?.delegate = self
        self.adBannerView?.hidden = false     
    }
```

The code shows as error-free.

It runs on my actual iPhone (simulator) and the in-app purchases work.

But the ad banners still show. I'm trying to **show** the ad banners with:

(i) In ViewController.swift:

```
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        self.adBannerView?.delegate = self
        self.adBannerView?.hidden = false
```

(ii) In InAppViewController.swift:

```
        self.adBannerView?.hidden = false
```

and **not show** the ad banners with:

(i) In ViewController.swift:

```
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        self.adBannerView?.delegate = self
        self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
```

(ii) In InAppViewController.swift:

```
        self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
```

but it's obviously not working.

**Questions:**

1. How can I amend my code and stop these ad banners from showing?
2. How can I **also** stop my interstitial ads from showing?

   I feel I'm close, very close ... but that cigar is yet to land!

Comment: is the method `removeAds` intentionally placed inside the function `btnRemoveAds:`. Whatever be the reason for its placement inside, that is perhaps the reason why you get the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'removeAds'`

Comment: Yes, you're right. I removed the method `removeAds` and replaced it just before the function `btnRemoveAds'. But I believe this code will still not work to remove all my Ad Banners and Interstitials.

Comment: Amended the code in my question accordingly.

Comment: Are you aware that iAd is shutting down on June 30, 2016, and they are not accepting new apps into iAd now.  So unless you are already on the app store with your app with iAd running then you'll need a different ad provider.  https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a

Comment: Yes. It is a confusing topic though. See this link : [link](https://www.macstories.net/linked/apple-discontinuing-iad-app-network/). "Developers will still be able to show iAd banners in their application; it’s just that the inventory for App Store apps to advertise will no longer exist."

Comment: As I understand it, you can still show ad banners for general products and services, websites, etc...  just not advertise other third party apps and promote.advertise your app(s) on other apps through the network. The question is, what % of the iAd market is made up of third party app promotion?

Comment: Im hoping to serve a mix of ads - iAd and other sources.

Comment: There was a lot of confusion on the web / blogs. But I think it's pretty clear if you ignore any external reporting. The Apple news article was clear the 'iAd App Network' was closing, the only question was what the 'iAd App Network' is, since us developers don't regularly use that name. If you look here https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_iAd you'll see Apples own use of the term means all of iAd for devs. I think the confusion is only coming from the external reporting, not from Apple.

Comment: Yes. Very good point. In case the iAd option is totally out for new apps to be submitted, I can just fill my ad banner and interstitial ad space with content from the likes of AdMob, Flurry, etc..? Sorry, on my first app personal development project and very new to all of this. Any info provided received with gratitude.

Comment: Good luck with your project.  I spent a lot of time building my ad solution, and a lot of time building a good iAd implementation alongside other providers, which is now wasted effort for me.  Thought I'd mention iAd closure so others don't waste their time as well.  (Btw Before I built my own solution I liked Fyber the best, although their customer support was a bit patchy at times, and they also take a commision, but they had a nice product. Unfortunately their iAd implementation was poor so I built my own solution because I really wanted iAd to be first preference !!!)

Comment: @RoryO'Bryan Thanks a lot. I'll look into Fyber. I'm spending a lot of time building everything! Currently allocating myself 10/10 for effort and time put-in, but perhaps 2/10 for quality of work achieved! lol. Irresistible force should be able to move this immovable rock, in time :-) Should say I'm loving every minute of it though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're implementing your own `ADBannerView` then you need to remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`.

`self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` can be used for a no hassle way of implementing iAd banners in your application. This will create an `ADBannerView` for you and show or hide the `ADBannerView` on the bottom of your view depending on whether it receives an ad or not from the iAd network.

You either implement your own `ADBannerView` or use `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`, not both.

Comment: Yes! You're right. I have used `self.adBannerView?.hidden = false
` or `self.adBannerView?.hidden = true` to show or hide ad banners respectively. Also, since there is no ad banner to display on my in-app purchase page (handled by `InAppViewController.swift`) I have removed any references to ad banners showing or not.

Comment: How can I hide my interstitial ads? I currently show them using `loadInterstitialAd()`

Comment: I think I have the solution. I have a button that generates a random message on screen for users. If the button is pressed, I check if the user has made in-app purchase to remove all ads. If the return is true (has purchased), I don't load interstitial ad; if the user has not made in-app purchase to remove all ads, I implement `loadInterstitialAd()`. Correct?

Comment: Apologies, no messaging capability for me. I have modified my code a lot past few hours. Should I repost amended code blow my original question above, or post a new question? It's regarding a restore button and the code associated with it.

Comment: @PaulSatem you should post a new question.

Comment: I have amended my new question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315949/in-app-purchase-restore-button-single-product-non-consumable) with what I think is the answer to my own question. If you're able to have a look I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `removeAds` is inside `btnRemoveAds` so move it outside. Secondly, one approach would be to save the product identifiers of the purchased products in UserDefaults so that on quit and launch of the app the ads will not appear since the user has purchased the inapp. So what you will do on `viewDidLoad` is check if the product identifier is purchased (from `NSUserDefaults`, if it was purchased earlier it will be set), if it is purchased disable ads from the beginning else show ads. And when item is purchased then set the state in `NSUserDefaults` and  update UI accordingly.

Comment: How would I do this? Sorry, I am very new to coding.